# Getting an OOM when rendering Bitmap for videoPlayer in Codename one app

Tags: codenameone

Just after calling show() on a form that has either a video or image displayed I am seeing this in the logs of my codenameOne Android app:

> 07-01 12:43:08.790 3369-3406/? E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 4631116 byte allocation with 4380676 free bytes and 4MB until OOM"
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4631116 byte allocation with 4380676 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:939)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:912)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.renderViewOnBitmap(AndroidNativeUtil.java:163)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.android.f$b.m_(AndroidImplementation.java:2652)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.y.B(PeerComponent.java:64)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.y.a(PeerComponent.java:211)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.h.b(Component.java:1323)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.h.d(Component.java:1297)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.h.a(Component.java:1272)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.i.a(Container.java:1323)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.h.b(Component.java:1323)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.h.d(Component.java:1297)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.h.a(Component.java:1272)
>   07-01 12:43:08.800 3369-3406/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.p.i.a(Container.java:1323)

It only seem to happen when the image is a large file, and every time with a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video is a [peer component](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/understanding-peer-native-components-why-codename-one-is-so-portable.html) which means that in order to implement transitions properly we try to convert it to an image and back again. For some reason this fails here.

We are looking at a different approach for peer components which is partially explained in [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1758). It should vastly improve things like video, html etc. but might be a bit challenging.

For now I would suggest disabling the transition to try to workaround this exception.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Sounds good but how do I disable transitions? Can you point me in the right direction for that? Thanks!

Comment: You can disable it on an individual form using `form.setTransitionOut(CommonTransitions.createEmpty())`. You can disable it globally using the theme constants but it's probably not what you want.